# Slick list mappings for like condition

Tags: scala, slick, scala-collections, slick-3.0

I have a table that has a column with values:

```
column
------
a
ab
abc
b
bc
bca
c
cba
```

I have a list = [a, b, bc], I want all the rows from the table which starts from any element in list.

```
column
------
a
ab
abc
b
bc
bca
```

How do i form queryCondition using slick:

```
table = TableQuery[Table]

mapping  = list map
        {
          value =>
            table.column like value + "%"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you'd like a query of the form:

```sql
SELECT column FROM table WHERE 
   column LIKE 'a%' 
OR column LIKE 'b%' 
OR column LIKE 'bc%'
```

That translates into Slick as basically:

```
val query = table.filter(row => 
 row.column like 'a%' || row.column like 'b%' || row.column like 'bc%'
)
```

So now the question is how to construct the `LIKE` parts from a Scala List.

The standard collections library has a few ways to do that. Here's one (`reduceLeft`):

```scala
val patterns = Seq("a", "b", "bc").map(_ + "%")
val query = table.filter(row => 
 patterns.map(pattern => row.column like pattern).reduceLeft(_ || _)
)
```

What we're doing is:

- turning the list of `patterns` into a list of Slick `like` expressions
- then combining the list of Slick expressions with `||`
- this gives us one Slick expression (the `like`s combined with `or`) to use inside a `filter`.

Instead of `like`, you can also use `startsWith` to avoid having to add `%` to your list of strings:

```scala
val patterns = Seq("a", "b", "bc")
val query = table.filter(row => 
 patterns.map(pattern => row.column startsWith pattern).reduceLeft(_ || _)
)
```

Slick will convert this into a Sql `LIKE` expression.